# Basic mysql query created on Dreamweaver not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a basic mysql query using dreamweaver (my php and mysql knowledge is very limited):

This is the code:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/ahbvc.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue         = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?     mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_ahbvc, $ahbvc);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT saida, DataRegisto, VIATURA, KMSAIDA, codigo, MORADA,    OpServiço FROM registo WHERE HORAENTRADA IS NULL ORDER BY saida";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $ahbvc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php do { ?>
<?php echo $row_Recordset1['']; ?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

But when i try to load the page i get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '§o FROM registo WHERE HORAENTRADA IS NULL ORDER BY saida' at line 1

can please some one help me ? I've searched every piece of the code but i cannot find the error.

Tks!

Comment: Don't use special characters when creating columns/tables/db names **OpServiço**

Comment: **DON'T** use Dreamweaver for coding.If you don't have a programming editor use Notepad till you get one. There are many free ones available. I use Notepad++(http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the

"OpServiço"

field name in your table, you could try to use backticks `OpServiço` to escape the table name, but in general it is recommended to only use lower-case characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz` and the underscore _ for database, table and field names

Comment: did you change the field name or did you use backticks? maybe there is no row in the database that matches your search. `HORAENTRADA IS NULL` looks suspiciously like it might fail all the time because there might be no null values for this field

Comment: I removed that field..

There are rows with "HORAENTRADA" empty, those are the record that i want loaded..

I want to return all the records that the field HORAENTRADA is empty.

Tks in advance

Comment: try escaping \`HORAENTRADA\` also

Comment: Hi Loopo, same result :(